# how to manage the data I insert into a table using BULK INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I have a **C# application** which captures data from a **csv** file to a **SQL table**

the text file looks like this

**students.csv**

```
Header 201501
id      code    amount
1       ab11    5000
2       ab11    6000
3       ab11    8000
3       wx34    2500
3       df21    1000
4       ab11    7000
4       zx54    3500
```

each item is in it own cell in the csv file. "I just spaced this so that you can see what is in the file".

basically I have to insert this data to two table but as you can see in the **id column** the are elements with the same number and **id is the primary key**.

the tables should look as follows:

**tblStudents**

```
id      code    amount
1       ab11    5000
2       ab11    6000
3       ab11    8000
4       ab11    7000
```

and the other table should have all data with data only with the **code that isn't "ab11"** and should have the **month which appears in csv file next to Header.**
And look as follows

**tblPaid**

```
Header 201501
id      code    amount month
3       wx34    2500   201501
3       df21    1000   201501
4       zx54    3500   201501
```

This is what I have at the moment but I can't seem to get a output

```
private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    btnNext.Enabled = true;

    openFileDialog1.Filter = ".csv file|*.csv*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        String file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        btnNext.Enabled = true;

        try
        {
            string connect = "Data Source=BRIAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PSAHoldings; user id =sa; Password=kagiso";

            string table = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='t_original' AND xtype='U')" +
                "CREATE TABLE t_original (" +
                "empId varChar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," +
                "paycode varChar(10) NOT NULL," +
                "amount int NOT NULL," +
                ")";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand createTable = new SqlCommand(table, con);
            createTable.ExecuteNonQuery();


            String BulkInsert = "BULK INSERT t_original FROM_" +
                file + "_WITH (--FIRSTROW = 3," +
                "FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'," +
                "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";

            SqlCommand bulkCmd = new SqlCommand(BulkInsert, con);
            bulkCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Exception Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

**I can't get anything into the table, My table is empty**

**t_original** is the table I have to insert the **students.csv** file into and I have to skip the first to lines

Any help and advise will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to add white space  `FROM_" + file + "_WITH` (I've used underscore for space)

Comment: How much rows are there in your data?

Comment: @YasirMajeed I don't know how many lines it has because the user has to open the file using 'openFileDialog' so **there will always be files every month some bigger and some smaller**

Comment: You can't do it this way (I think)... The file is on the (local) computer of the user, the SQL is on another computer. The BULK INSERT can't "see" the file on the user computer.

Comment: and `ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n'`

Comment: What have you got in your `catch` block? Your `BULK INSERT` statement won't work, because you've commented part of it out. The BulkInsert string will evaluate to `BULK INSERT tblStudents FROM {file} WITH (`. Everything after is commented out, and therefor you'll get a syntax error. This will be caught in your `catch`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I just edited my code to show my `catch` block

Comment: Is an exception thrown? Also, can you check what `BulkInsert` actually evaluates to?

Comment: @HoneyBadger now I'm not getting any exceptions, I have edited my code and question but I can't get anything into the table

Answer (score 0):

You took the comment of @StuartLC too literal; as he said, the underscores in his comment represent spaces. The effect of the added underscores is that it now reads: 
`BULK INSERT t_original FROM_{file}` (notice lack of space between `from` and file). The same goes for the underscore in front of `WITH`.

Furthermore, the double dash (`--`) represent a comment, so everything after it is not executed.

If you debug, and get the actual value of `BulkInsert`, and execute that statement I would be very surprised if it executes, it will probably make the errors a whole lot easier to find.