# How to skip first 2 lines and last line when I use BULK INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, csv

Hi I have a application whereby the user browese for a csv file and the the data in the csv file should be written into a table only by using `BULK INSERT`

the text file looks something like this

```
Student_head    201501  
student_id  code    amount
1           salb    10015
2           salb    10016
3           salb    10017
4           c100    4000
5           salb    10022
END
```

**What I need to do is skip the first 2 lines and the last line.**

I should get something like this:

```
    1           salb    10015
    2           salb    10016
    3           salb    10017
    4           c100    4000
    5           salb    10022
```

I have tried this code but nothing seems to be happening

```
        openFileDialog1.Filter = ".csv file|*.csv*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            String file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
                string[] splitedLine = firstLine.Split(';');
                string month = splitedLine[1];
            }
            try
            { 
                string connect = "Data Source=George-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Students; user id =sa; Password=george1";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
                con.Open();

                String BulkInsert = "BULK INSERT t_original FROM" +
                    file + "WITH (FIRSTROW = 3," +
                    "FIELDTERMINATOR = ''," +
                    "MAXERRORS = 0," +
                    "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')";
                //"UPDATE t_original"+
                //"SET month =" + month + 
                //"WHERE month is null";

                SqlCommand bulkCmd = new SqlCommand(BulkInsert, con);
                bulkCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help and advise will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Can you pre-process your file and remove the lines you don't want imported?

Comment: @LeeWillis that is the problem, this application will be used by many people and the csv files will be different but with more of the same data inside. the first 2 and last lines should always get skipped

Comment: Didn't you already ask his and someone pointed out that you're missing a space after FROM and before  WITH?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to manage the data I insert into a table using BULK INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363575/how-to-manage-the-data-i-insert-into-a-table-using-bulk-insert)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `SqlCommand`, try using a [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Something like...

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
    //turn your CSV data into a DataTable using your favorite CSV parser.
    //My favorite is [`TextFieldParser`][2].

using SqlBulkCopy copier = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString,
                  SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity Or SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls) {
    // Now set up your column mappings via SqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings
    // Choose a destination table with SqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName

    // execute the copy
    copier.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: As I started reading about `TextFieldParser` I got to understand that there is another way of doing it besides the `BULK INSERT` way

Comment: Thanks, `TextFieldParser` is new to me but I see it's very helpful